# Hiding partially a curve/path/edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

I would like to hide the b-i edge when it passes all between the edges f-l and h-c ( not only at the intersection).
I would need a solution that *doesn't* force me to compute manually the slope at (f) and (h).

Idealy I would like to be able to "turn off" any drawing of a curve between two points of the given curve.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,circle}]

\node (b) at (0,5){b};
\node (c) at (8,5){c};


\node (f) at (0,2){f};
\node (h) at (1,0){h};
\node (i) at (7,0){i};
\node (l) at (6,5){l};





\draw (f) edge [name path=pf, line width=2pt, in=-90, out=0] (l);
\draw (b) edge [ name path=pb, line width=2pt, in=180, out=-90] (i);
\draw (h) edge [name path=ph, line width=2pt, in=-90, out=0]  (c);

\node [name intersections={of=pb and ph, by={e}}, fill=white] at (e) {e};
\node [name intersections={of=pb and pf, by={d}}, fill=white] at (d) {d};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: I want to erase the curve between (d) and (e)]

Comment: Do you want to remove the portion of b-i between nodes d and e?

Comment: Yes exactly (preferably by keeping the edge b-i, and "turning it off" somehow).

Comment: I edited my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a dirty solution that drawing an ellipse between nodes `d` and `e` and redraw them.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,shapes,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={draw,circle}]

\node (b) at (0,5){b};
\node (c) at (8,5){c};
\node (f) at (0,2){f};
\node (h) at (1,0){h};
\node (i) at (7,0){i};
\node (l) at (6,5){l};

\draw (f) edge [name path=pf, line width=2pt, in=-90, out=0] (l);
\draw (b) edge [name path=pb, line width=2pt, in=180, out=-90] (i);
\draw (h) edge [name path=ph, line width=2pt, in=-90, out=0]  (c);

\node [name path=circe,name intersections={of=pb and ph, by={e}},fill=white] at (e) {e};
\node [name path=circd,name intersections={of=pb and pf, by={d}},fill=white] at (d) {d};
\path [name intersections={of=circd and pb, by={d1,d2}}];
\path [name intersections={of=circe and pb, by={ee}}];

\path let
         \p1 = ($(d2.north east)-(ee.south west)$),
         \n1 = {veclen(\p1)}
         in
         (d2.south) -- (ee.north) 
         node[white,midway, sloped, draw, ellipse,fill=white, 
              minimum width=\n1, minimum height=\n1/4] {};

\node [name path=circe,name intersections={of=pb and ph, by={e}}] at (e) {e};
\node [name path=circd,name intersections={of=pb and pf, by={d}}] at (d) {d};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A little bit too circumstential. Idealy I would like to turn off any curve between two given points of the curve